# Avoiding comma separator for the last value

Tags: asp.net

I am generating an output on a webpage in a format like this

> ({"1":"Jeff","2":"Tom","3":"Michael",})

For this, basically this is the code I am using

```
Response.Write("(" + "{");
//
for (Int32 i = 0; i < k.Length; i++)
{
  Response.Write(Convert.ToString(k.GetValue(i)) + ",");
}
//
Response.Write("}" + ")");
```

Notice my output, after Michael" there is a comma which I do not want since this is the last vaue but this is appearing since `,` is in the for loop. How to prevent this/remove this last comma from appearing?

My output should be `({"1":"Jeff","2":"Tom","3":"Michael"})` (There's no comma after last value here)

Comment: The same question was asked yesterday by somebody.

Comment: @Al Kepp - Do you have a link to it?

Comment: Which framework version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `k` is an array of strings

```
List<string> tokens = k.ToList<string>();
Response.Write("({" + String.join<string>(",", tokens) + "})");
```

Comment: I like this way better than mine.  You might edit it to take into account that k.GetValue(i) apparently returns something like "1":"Jeff"

Comment: I'm not a .NET expert, so I wasn't sure about the type of 'k'. How would you change this? When I used PHP, implode(...) was my best friend, so I just tried to translate that into C#.

Answer (score 2):

Simplified and VB.Net, but i think you will get it:

```
Dim values As New List(Of String)(New String() {"1:Jeff", "2:Tom", "3:Michael"})
Dim result As String = "({" & String.Join(",", values.ToArray) & "})"
```

If k is a Collection like Array,List etc.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the number of iterations and how often this happens use StringBuilder instead.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (Int32 i = 0; i < k.Length; i++)
{
    sb.Append(",");
    sb.Append(Convert.ToString(k.GetValue(i)));
}
if (sb.Length > 0)  {
    sb.Remove(0,1);
}
Response.Write(String.Format("({{{0}}})", sb.ToString()));
```

Another way is:  However, it has to check every iteration.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (Int32 i = 0; i < k.Length; i++)
{
    if (sb.Length > 0) { 
      sb.Append(","); 
    }
    sb.Append(Convert.ToString(k.GetValue(i)));
}
Response.Write(String.Format("({{{0}}})", sb.ToString()));
```

Comment: I think this is the faster way, and you are faster than me :) in the answer also. :)

Comment: @Aristos: String.Join is the fastest if you already have an Array.

Answer (score 0):

If you change how you output to write the first object in the collection then everyone after preceded by a comma it should work fine.

```
        Response.Write("(" + "{");
        //
        Response.Write(Convert.ToString(k.GetValue(0)));
        for (Int32 i = 1; i < k.Length; i++)
        {
            Response.Write("," + Convert.ToString(k.GetValue(i)));
        }
        //
        Response.Write("}" + ")");
```

An alternative would be writing to a stringbuilder and outputting all but the last character

Comment: There is a problem with your commas.  Assuming three elements the result would be value1, , value2, value3

Comment: @Chris Lively damn, that'll teach me to copy and paste without reading properly, editing it now

Answer (score 0):

you can decrease your loop instead increase... like

for (Int32 i = k.Length; i > 0; i--)

and put: if (i == 1) removeComa;

Answer (score 0):

```
Response.Write("(" + "{");
//
for (Int32 i = 0; i < k.Length; i++)
{
  Response.Write(Convert.ToString(k.GetValue(i)) + (i == k.Length - 1 ? "" : ","));
}
//
Response.Write("}" + ")");
```

Answer (score 0):

One of my favorite fixes for this is to use a prepend instead and only set comma as the seperator value after the first item (sorry for the VB):

```
    Dim seperator As String = ""

    For i As Integer = 0 To k.Length
        Response.Write(seperator + Convert.ToString(k.GetValue(i)))
        seperator = ","
    Next
```

Comment: Because strings are immutable you are creating a new one for each iteration.  For small lists this would be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, simply use insert a "break" when the count reaches the last digit and that has been processed?